# (Cisco) Multiple interfaces for a VLAN?

Tags: cisco, vlan

Noob question. From what I read there can only be a single SVI associated with a VLAN. However I am able to create multiple interfaces for VLAN 1.

```
SWITCH2#show ip interface

    IP Address        I/F    I/F Status  Type   Directed  Prec Redirect Status
                             admin/oper         Broadcast
------------------ --------- ---------- ------- --------- ---- -------- ------
192.168.1.150/24   vlan 1    UP/DOWN    Static  disable   No   enable   Valid
192.168.2.151/24   vlan 1    UP/DOWN    Static  disable   No   enable   Valid

SWITCH2#
```

Also a switch comes with a default interface for VLAN 1 (I can use that IP to access the web management console in a browser). Now if I am going to connect two (or more) switches together then that implies that there'll be 2 interfaces in VLAN 1.(I would need 2 different IPs to access the web interface of the 2 switches)

Where I am getting wrong? Somewhere I am getting confused between the following terms and aspects,

1. Management Interface(s) for VLAN 1 (I understand management doesn't need to be 1)
2. VLAN Interface
3. SVI

Any inputs will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single SVI is a single interface with the name **vlanX**. What you are showing here is the SVI interface with more than one IP address. This is common and this is valid. One is *primary*, all others are *secondary*.

1) Management interface for a switch can be any of SVI interfaces, but it can also be a dedicated *out-of-band* interface, if the switch has one.

2) This is actually a SVI.

3) There's indeed only one SVI per vlan. It's optional, but every switch has at least one out of the box for *vlan 1* usually.

Comment: Thx. very helpful. clear now